# How do I make this script fire when I click a Fusion Tables layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I have a Fusion Table layer on my map. I want to make it so that when I click on the Fusion Table layer, this script fires.

My code so far:

```
gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
google.maps.event.addListener(gmap,'click',function(e){
  console.log(e);
}); // DONE: google.maps.event.addListener
```

When I click a part of the map that has no Fusion Table layer on it, the script fires. But if I click a part of the Fusion Table layer, it doesn't.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either set the `clickable`-option of the FusionTablesLayer to `false` or also observe the `click`-event of the FusionTablesLayer

Comment: What do you mean by "observe the `click`-event"?

Comment: `addListener` observes an event, do the same you do with `gmap` with the FusionTablesLayer

Comment: Ah, you mean something like `layerVarName.event.addListener(...);`? OK, I'll try...

Comment: `google.maps.event.addListener(layerVarName,'click',function(e){console.log(e);});`